# singular cube in manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

In his *Calculus on Manifolds* Spivak writes (page 97) that

> A singular *n*-cube in $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous function $c: 
> [0,1]^n \mapsto A$ (here $[0,1]^n$ denotes the *n*-fold product $[0,1] \times... \times [0,1]$), etc.

What is "singular" about a singular n-cube?

Comment: It's singular because it is not required to be injective... Worse, it can collapse dimensions. For instance, a map from the unit square into $A$ can actually look like a curve if, say $f(x,y)=f(x,0)$ for every $y$. It's hard to think of it as just a square in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if it actually looks more like a line segment.